# Keep statusbar bounds when hiding it?

Tags: ios, swift, uistatusbar

Im hiding the status bar like this: `UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden = (Bool)`

Now it hides it, but it also makes its bounds disappear, when it is hiding the mainViewcontroller's view frame is changing, its getting taller.

Is it possible to change the alpha for the status bar or something similar?

Comment: Can't you modify the frame of the mainViewController's view, or if using Autolayout, set a constraint towards Top Layout Guide?

Comment: It is also a NavigationViewController and its navigationbar shrinks also. Maybe I need to change my question but its actually the navigation bar I dont want to get resized.

Comment: What do you mean by NavigationBar shrinks? That it starts with a y position at 0 and with a height of 44 points?

Comment: When the statusbar is visible the navigigation is on screen at y: 20, but when the statusbar is hidden it goes to on screen y:0

Comment: I said it shrinks because it looks like it shrinks in ios 7+

Comment: Oh I see. Then I'm not sure if that's possible. I recommend you read the Human Interface Guidelines regarding the status bar. Found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/Bars.html).